# Як перекласти «Back-of-the-envelope calculation»

Tags: переклад, from-english, вибір-слова

Прямий переклад як-от *обчислення на задньому боці конверта* звучить досить довго і не викликає якихось асоціації в україномовного споживача.

Колись я чув, що в Ґуґлі серветки зумисно роблять твердішими, щоб на обіді люди могли записувати свої думки у разі чого, то думав може *обчислення на серветці*, але не певен частково ще й тому, що серветка не асоціюється з тим, на чому можна більш-менш багато писати.

Також можна подумати про *обчислення на берегах*, наче зошит закінчився і вільне місце лише на берегах, де можна зробити короткі обчислення. Те саме про береги книги.

Чи є інші варіанти чи обґрунтування цих?

РЕД: ось наявні у Вікіпедії переклади іншими мовами (наводжу тільки варіанти відмінні від англомовного):

- іспанська - розрахунки/обчислення на серветці
- німецька - грубі розрахунки/обчислення
- французька - розрахунки/обчислення на кутику столу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Швидкі) Розрахунки/обчислення на папірці

(Швидкі) Розрахунки/обчислення на берегах

(Швидкі) Розрахунки/обчислення на звороті конверта

(Швидкі) Розрахунки/обчислення на чомусь під рукою

(Швидкі) Розрахунки/обчислення на серветці

(Швидкі) Розрахунки/обчислення на клаптику

Щось з цього ряду вирішує проблему?

З усіх цих варіантів найбільш орґанічно мені звучать папірець, береги й те, що було під рукою.

Comment: Ич, не подумав, що треба казати *на звороті*, а не *на задньому боці*. Дякую. Тепер думаю про береги і зворотний бік. Та й про те чи то *розрахунки*, чи то *обчислення* треба помікувати.

Comment: @Yola тішуся, що вдалося розкидати вектори можливостей трохи в боки. Це, в принципі, єдине, на що сподівався, бо конкретний переклад завжди залежатиме від контексту сильно.

Comment: Додам, що вини радше приблизні ніж швидкі.

Comment: @Yola коли йдеться про розрахунки, для мене це синоніми.